# Python 3 generating MP4 files via MP4Box

Tags: python, python-3.x, mp4, mp4box

I overhauled my code to use popen and still not getting a new MP4 file.

If I manually type it out in terminal MP4Box works.

But when I run the code below it doesn't raise any error whatsoever. So I am puzzled as what is not working.

The two definition are for tkinter GUI buttons.

```
global now

#put widgets here

def picapture():
    try:
            global now
            debugLog.insert(0.0, "Date Initialization Done\n")
            now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%F_%X")
            debugLog.insert(0.0, now + "\n")
            camera.start_preview(fullscreen=False,window = (200,0,1100,640))
            camera.start_recording('/home/pi/' + now + '.h264')
    except:
            print(traceback.format_exc(limit=10))

def stopcapture():
    try:
            global now
            camera.stop_recording()
            camera.stop_preview()
            MP4Box_Command = ['MP4Box', '-add', now + '.h264', '-0', now + '.mp4']
            convert = subprocess.Popen(MP4Box_Command, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            raise RunTimeError("Commmand '{}'return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd,e.returncode,e.output))
    except:
            print(traceback.format_exc(limit=10))
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: The only thing that I call see is that `subprocess.call` waits until the command finishes but as the command is a video encoder that takes a while to finish and so in the meantime it blocks the GUI from updating. You need to use `subprocess.Popen` instead and poll for the processes exit in the GUI loop.

Comment: Updated to use Subprocess.popen instead. Still no luck.